# Submission of a form with file input using ajax in php in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Myself pushpendra working on php CI i have to submit a form which has two text box and one file input for image upload i want to open this form on ajax and then submit this also also on ajax like add photo feature of facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You could read this , it should help. [Upload Files With CI Ajax](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-upload-files-with-codeigniter-and-ajax/). Have sample codes as well so that you'll get to know how its done.

Hope it helps